# Using Eval() in body

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

I have Football Leagues site and I want to change my background with admin panel but my background in my master page's body section like

```
<body style="background-image:url('images/Arkaplanlar/Webp.net-resizeimage1.png')">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="auto-style1">
        <uc1:Header runat="server" ID="Header" /></div>
        <div style="margin-left:300px; width:700px; height:20px">&nbsp;</div>
        <div style="margin-left:300px; width:700px; height:25px" class="auto-style2">
            <uc1:Menu runat="server" ID="Menu" />
        </div>
        <div style="margin-left:300px; width:700px; height:20px">&nbsp;</div>
        <div style="margin-left:300px; " class="auto-style6">

            <div style="width:200px; float:left; height:auto; background-color:darkred; margin-left:0px;">
                <strong><span class="auto-style7">LİGLER</span></strong><br />
                <br />
                <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" Width="200px">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <div style="border: thin solid #CCCCCC">
                          <a href="LigDetay.aspx?LigId=<%# Eval("LigId") %>" class="a">  <strong>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" CssClass="auto-style80" Text='<%# Eval("LigAd") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </strong></a>
                            &nbsp;(
                            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("LigAdet") %>'></asp:Label>
                            )</div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:DataList>
            </div>
            <div style="width:450px; float:left; height:auto; background-color:darkred; margin-left:50px;">
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            </div>
        </div>
        <uc1:Footer runat="server" ID="Footer" />
    </form>     
</body>
```

and I want to get that background with my database. I tried

```
ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ArkaplanImg") %>'
```

instead of

```
style="background-image:url('images/Arkaplanlar/Webp.net-resizeimage1.png')"
```

but i keep getting Validation (HTML5): Attribute 'ImageUrl' is not a valid attribute of element 'body'.

Comment: we don't have enough info to know why that didn't work. We need a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and a better description of the actual behaviour of the code (i.e. tell us what it _does_ do, instead of what you expected it to do).

Comment: Where is the code block of this `style="background-image:url('images/Arkaplanlar/Webp.net-resizeimage1.png')" `?

Comment: Can you try `theBody.Style["background-image"] = ArkaplanImg;` in the code behind file? in `Page_Load()` maybe?

Comment: It's in the body but I don't know why body part is deleted

Comment: @OguzOzgul i tried that and i get The name 'Body' does not exist in the current context and The name 'ArkaplanImg' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Sorry for that, please add these yo your body element: `runat="server" id="theBody"`. Secondly, assign to this, whatever you are getting with `Eval("ArkaplanImg")`. What does Eval() evaluate from in here?

Comment: @OguzOzgul  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Img = Request.QueryString["ArkaplanImg"];
        if (Img == null)
        {
            Img = "'images//Arkaplanlar//" + "Webp.net-resizeimage1.png'";
        }
        theBody.Style["background-image"] = Img;          i do that and it work (thanks to you) but i have just one question how am i gonna take that image from my database.

Comment: How did you do it earlier? What was the value given by Eval("ArkaplanImg") ?